# Open a file in Vim without it showing in the buffer list

Tags: vim, tmux

My Vim workflow revolves around having multiple open buffers, and switching between them with a combination of `:ls<CR>:b $BUFFER_NUMBER`, `:bp`, `:bn` and `b#`. As such I like to have some control over my buffer list, so tend to relatively frequently `:bd` buffers that I'm not using.

I'm often working primarily on a few files, but need to access many more to look briefly. After working in this way for a while, new files end up with a very high buffer index. Navigating to `:b 75` is quite inconvenient, but also "feels" wrong. To mitigate this I tend to open another instance of Vim in a different tmux pane to open files I know I just need to glance at, but it feels like this should be something I can solve with Vim!

I understand it isn't possible to reset the buffer index, or re-number the current buffer list, but I wonder whether it's possible to open a buffer without it showing in the buffer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing tool in your tool belt is `:b partialname<Tab>`, which lets you access a specific buffer without having to choose from a long list or needlessly switch through dozens of unrelated buffers.

In the gifcast below I have 634 loaded buffers (`$ vim *.js` in `node_modules/lodash`). This is a bit extreme, maybe, but I think it makes it very clear how easy and painless buffer switching can be in Vim, no matter how many buffers you have. And without any plugin.

[image: btab]

See `:help :b` and `:help wildmenu`.

---

Here are the relevant parts of my `vimrc`:

```
" three options
set wildmenu
set wildignorecase
set wildmode=full

" one mapping
nnoremap ,b :buffer<Space>
```

Note: my actual `,b` mapping includes a `*` but it is not necessary; it's there only for consistency with another set of mappings.

Comment: Good suggestion, though this is actually in my toolbox already. The problem I find is that I frequently have files that are very similar in name, due to the structure of projects I work on. For example: `something.controller`, `something.module` `something-else.controller` `something-else.module`. In this case, trying to match either `...controller` or `something-else` would not allow me to quickly switch files.

Comment: Worst case you get to choose between 5 or 6 candidates. A couple of `<Tab>` and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the real answer to your question is no.  All buffers are associated with a buffer number when they are first opened. This buffer number is consumed and never available to be used again, even when using `:bwipeout` to completely remove a buffer.